# Красивый вывод таблицы в консоль

Tags: c#, вывод

Помогите пожалуйста красиво вывести табличку в консоль. Видел примеры с целыми числами, но у меня числа с запятой и никак не получается все красиво оформить.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
        double y = 0;
        for (double x = a; x <= b;)
        {
            if (x < 93)
            {
                y = a + b * x;
            }
            else if ((x>=93)&&(x<=120))
            {
                y = b - a * x;
            }
            else if (x>120)
            {
                y = a * b * x;
            }
            Console.WriteLine("{0,-3}    |     {1}", x,y);
            x += h;
        }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Строка вывода в консоль (где "10" - выделяемое количество ячеек под вывод параметра)

```
Console.WriteLine("{0,10}   |{1,10}", x,y);
```

Результат:

```
 -93,5   |    2312,3
    93   |       -22
```

Comment: Спасибо, получилось :)